# Show that $\lim_{y \to 0} f(x+iy)$ exists for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is part of a question in Rudin's RCA. It says that if $f$ is holomorphic in the upper half plane and satisfies
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{0<y<\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x+iy)|^2 dx<\infty,
\end{equation*} then
\begin{equation*}
f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(\xi+i\epsilon)}{\xi+i\epsilon-z}d\xi
\end{equation*} holds for $0<\epsilon<y$. I can prove this part by using paley and wiener with a semicircle in the upper half plane. However, I got stuck with the second question of showing that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{y \to 0} f(x+iy)
\end{equation*} exists for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Any suggestions or hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a linear fractional transformation $\phi$ to map the unit disk $D$ conformally onto the upper half plane. Consider $F=f \circ \phi$ which is analytic in $D$. Also it is clear that $F$ is bounded a.e. in $D$ so that $\|F\|_\infty<\infty$. Now we may apply Fatou's Theorem to conclude that $F(re^{it})$ exists a.e. as $r \to 1$. By transforming back to $f$, we can show that the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim_{y \to 0} f(x+iy)
\end{equation} exists a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$.